# Can I publish a managed package on AppExchange that was made in a different developer org?

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, isv, app-development, partner

I have a regular developer org on which I have developed a managed package. I now want to publish it on AppExchange. I just read that I need an ISV partner account in order to do this. It seems this ISV account would have a few different orgs attached to it for development and testing.

Can I attach my existing dev org to the new partners account so I can publish the package I've already built? I don't want to have to copy the code over to a new dev org with a different namespace.

EDIT 6/15/15:
It looks like I can apply to become a partner using my current login for my dev org. Hopefully this means that my original dev org will be able to use the License Management Organization that comes with becoming a partner.

Comment: You can link your dev org to the ISV org you are provided with. Once you get the nomenclature and process down it will go quickly.....But rest assured that you will be able to link up the existing dev org to the new ISV org either via your publishing console or by calling SF

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed to know. Do you want to put that in the form of an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can link your dev org to the ISV org you are provided with. Once you get the nomenclature and process down it will go quickly.....But rest assured that you will be able to link up the existing dev org to the new ISV org either via your publishing console or by calling SF